# Merging 2 arrays keeping values from both

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to merge to arrays using array_merge however I'm either not doing it right or this function doesn't do what I'm expecting.

Here I have 2 arrays

```php
array_merge($array[0], $array[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [apples] => 1
            [pears] => 
            [oranges] => 
            [grapes] => 
            [melons] => 1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [apples] => 
            [pears] => 1
            [oranges] => 1
            [grapes] => 
            [melons] => 
            [pineapples] => 
            [bananas] => 
            [lemons] => 
        )

)
```

I'm getting this back, which is just seems to be using the second array

```
 Array
        (
            [apples] => 
            [pears] => 1
            [oranges] => 1
            [grapes] => 
            [melons] => 
            [pineapples] => 
            [bananas] => 
            [lemons] => 
        )
```

But my desired outcome is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [apples] => 1
            [pears] => 1
            [oranges] => 1
            [grapes] => 
            [melons] => 1
            [pineapples] => 
            [bananas] => 
            [lemons] => 

        )
)
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php): "If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one."

Comment: Before doing the merge, you might want to [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) any keys that have empty values.

Comment: What about if first array has 'apples' => 1 and second array has 'apples' => 1 too? Do you want to be 'apples' => 2 in the resulting array or what? If yes, you will need to code it yourself, not to simply apply a function as array_merge.

Comment: what happen if `apple=>1` is there in both array? then it will become `apple=>2` in final array or `apple=>1` will remain??

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then **the later value** for that key **will overwrite the previous one**.

If you want the ones from either that contain values to overwrite empty ones in either, then filter out the empties:

```
$result = array_merge(array_filter($array[0]), array_filter($array[1]));
```

However, if both arrays have the same key and they both have a value then this will still result in the second value.  Also, this will not keep keys that are empty in both arrays like `pineapples` so you might need to loop and check what you want to include or not, or possibly:

```
$result = array_merge(array_merge(array_filter($array[0]), array_filter($array[1])),
                      array_filter($array[0]),
                      array_filter($array[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method I.** Use `array_walk_recursive`

```
array_walk_recursive($a, function($v, $k) use (&$r){
    isset($r[$k]) ? (!$v ? '' : ($r[$k] = $v)) : ($r[$k] = $v); 
});
print_r($r);
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/UpR2f

**Method 2.** Iterate using `foreach` with ternary operator

```
$r = [];
foreach($a as $k => $v){
  foreach($v as $k1 => $v1){
    isset($r[$k1]) ? ($v1==1 ? ($r[$k1] = $v1) : '') : ($r[$k1] = $v1);
  }
}
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/WXCpd

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep keys that are empty in both arrays you can loop and merge the arrays by yourself.

You can take first array, that add keys from second array in foreach loop.

```
$result = $array[0];
foreach ($array[1] as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

This will keep the values from the first array if there are conflicting keys. If you rather want to keep the values from second array you can do following.

```
$result = $array[0];
foreach ($array[1] as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```